# using python quote_plus with slashes

Tags: python, flask, urllib

I'm using `quote_plus` from `urllib` which works great along with its cousin `unquote_plus`, for making pluses between the spaces such that: `The Cat Sat` becomes `The+Cat+Sat` which is great. However now the issue is that using this effects the path when I have `/description/id/34/the cat sat on` becomes something like this

```
%2Fdescription%2F274%2Fthe+cat+sat+on
```

What should I do. I really want the plusses for the spaces, but I'm torn between doing just a replace on spaces for plusses. Is there a proper treatment in building up the path to start with. I really want to preserve the slashes and the plusses.

Flask template view:

```
<a href="{{animal.url|quote_plus}}">{{animal.title}}</a>
```

in the code.py:

```
animal["url"] = "/description/"+str(animal["id"]) + "/" + animal["title"]
```

also:

```
app.jinja_env.filters['quote_plus'] = lambda u: quote_plus(u)
```

Comment: Can you share the actual snippet of code you're using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call quote_plus, set safe='/', which is what you are asking for.

Check out the docs at https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html
Notice that quote has a default parameter safe='/'
wherease quote_plus has a default safe=''

```
urllib.parse.quote(string, safe='/', encoding=None, errors=None)
urllib.parse.quote_plus(string, safe='', encoding=None, errors=None)
```

The difference is illustrated here:

```
url = '/description/id/34/the cat sat on'
print 'quote: ', urllib.quote(url)
print 'quote_plus: ', urllib.quote_plus(url)
print 'quote_plus with safe set: ', urllib.quote_plus(url, safe='/')
```

output

```
quote:  /description/id/34/the%20cat%20sat%20on
quote_plus:  %2Fdescription%2Fid%2F34%2Fthe+cat+sat+on
quote_plus with safe set:  /description/id/34/the+cat+sat+on
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using `urllib.quote` instead of `urllib.quote_plus`? It will quote '+' with '%20' and leave slash unchanged. I think it is not customisable, because it should conform with certain url standard.

Comment: I really wanted plus, as this looks so much nicer when a website is indexed and more human readable too.

Comment: Then have try to replace '%20' with '+', then still use unquote_plus to convert it back. I just tried and it works.